# Eclipse template for unicode symbols in text/properties file

Tags: eclipse, templates, unicode, properties

I want to define some templates for certain characters in unicode.
for example `\ä + ctrl + space` will convert to `\u00E4` etc.
Tried defining a template under `General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> WikiText -> Templates`, but this did not work (tried it in `.properties` file).

Do I have to configure something else or isnt it possible at all?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `WikiText` is only for the `WikiText` editor, not for `.properties` (or Java or anything else). The properties file editor does not seem to support templates (see `Preferences > Java > Properties Files Editor` for the few settings it does have.